# Variable being deallocated after function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a beginner in C++ and ran into a problem. Please see my code below. The issue is described in the inline comments.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include<vector>

// #include "test.hpp"

using namespace std;
vector<string*> test();

int main() {
    vector<string*> ret = test();
    cout << ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: Memory of String str
    cout << *ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: random undefined behavior
                                 //I want this to output "s"
}

vector<string*> test() {
    vector<string*> ret;
    string str = "t";
    ret.push_back(&str);
    cout << ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: Memory of String str
    cout << *ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: "t"
    str[0] = 's';
    cout << ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: Memory of String str
    cout << *ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: "s"
    return ret;
}
```

Basically I want to have it so that I can declare an object in a function body, add it to a vector, and be able to modify the object again later in the function (any time in the future) and be able to see these changes anywhere I have this vector. This can be easily done in Java, but I'm having trouble doing it in C++.

Comment: You can't use the string after it has been destructed.

Comment: Use `vector<string>` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change this:

```
string str = "t";
ret.push_back(&str);
```

To this:

```
string* str = new string("t");
ret.push_back(str);
```

The problem is that in your original example your string gets destroyed when you exit `test()`, meaning that its memory address now points at nothing. To avoid this, you want to allocate `str` on the heap by using a pointer so that the memory isn't cleaned up after you exit `test()`.

Just remember that whenever you manually allocate memory in C++, you must deallocate it to avoid memory leaks:

```
for (string* i : ret) {
    delete i;
}
```

Comment: .. and then end up with a memory leak. Might be worth a mention

Comment: I disagree with this solution. You are just teaching them how to leak memory or get bogged down in manual memory management.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I've updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: I still don't feel good about this. With manual memory management you're responsible for deleting the object(s) once and at the right time. It opens you up to double-delete and use-after-free bugs. Note: I'm not a downvoter just a mild critic.

Comment: @Blastfurnace That may be, but other answers have already covered the dynamic angles of the question. OP uses manual memory allocation in his question, and mentions that he wants to be able to see changes in the string reflected in the vector, which can be accomplished with pointers, so it's entirely appropriate to address this in an answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. The original problem wasn't with Strings. I just used Strings to demonstrate the issue. I am actually doing this with a custom object. In the case of deconstructing, do I need to code a custom deconstructor or can I rely on C++'s general deconstructor (which is called when the program terminates)?

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. As per your second question, you'll only need a custom destructor if the objects you have do manual memory management. For instance, if your custom class has members that are pointers and you call `new` somewhere to initialise these, then you'll want a custom destructor to call `delete` on them as well.

Comment: As @Blastfurnace has pointed out, this is easy to forget or mess up, so if you're worried about it I'd suggest looking into smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` - They have certain advantages over raw pointers (such as automatically deallocating memory on destruction) that are quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Objects declared with automatic lifetime always cease to exist when the scope in which they were created is left.

If you want an object to survive beyond the scope in which it was created you must create the object with dynamic lifetime, using (directly or indirectly) the `new` keyword.  Remember though, C++ has no garbage collector, so for every use of `new` you *must* `delete` the created object when you're done with it.  The best way to do that is to use some form of smart pointer, like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (which to use depends on your exact situation):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> test() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> ret;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> str = std::make_unique<std::string>("t");
    ret.push_back(std::move(str));
    //...
    return ret;
}
```

([`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) uses `new` to create a new object and returns a `std::unique_ptr` to it)

---

In this particular case there's really no advantage to storing pointers to strings in your vector though.  A `std::string` object is essentially a smart pointer to an array of characters, so you can just store the objects directly:

```
std::vector<std::string> test() {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    ret.push_back("t");
    //...
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You could add how it is possible to create a reference to the object in the vector to make the "be able to modify the object again later in the function" part cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using pointers. They have their place in C++ but not in the code you've posted.

The specific problem is this:

```
string str = "t";
ret.push_back(&str);
```

You are storing a pointer to a function-local `std::string` object. At the end of the function the `std::string` goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving you with a dangling pointer and undefined behavior.

Change `vector<string*> ret;` to `vector<string> ret;`. Store objects instead of pointers, value semantics are easier to reason about. Standard library containers and strings are designed to do the right thing and make all of this simple.

Comment: If I do this, then I can't modify the string I added anymore. ```str[0] = 's';``` no longer works. My end goal is to do this for any generic object. I just used strings to simplify the code to show the issue.

Comment: @JustinWang I don't know what your real code looks like but this sounds far-fetched. Using a `std::vector<some_type>` absolutely **does not** prevent you from modifying the elements of the vector.

Comment: It definitely does, here's something I wrote up real fast to illustrate this ```vector<string> v;
    string test = "t";
    v.push_back(test);
    test[0] = 's';
    cout << v.back() << endl;
```
Output is 't' rather than 's'.

Comment: @JustinWang Your question wasn't clear that you wanted a vector of **references** to objects that exist outside the vector. Your problem is object lifetime, not the vector. You might solve that with dynamic allocation and smart pointers. Holding raw pointers in a vector raises the question of who owns the objects and who frees their memory. Good luck with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing back the address of a local variable. When the variable goes out of scope, that memory address is freed.

You can use unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead, something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

// #include "test.hpp"

using namespace std;
vector<std::shared_ptr<string>> test();

int main() {
    vector<std::shared_ptr<string>> ret = test();
    cout << ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: Memory of String str
    cout << *(ret.back()) << endl; //Outputs: "t"
}

vector<std::shared_ptr<string>> test() {
    vector<std::shared_ptr<string>> ret;
    const auto str = std::make_shared<string>("t");
    ret.push_back(str);
    cout << ret.back() << endl; //Outputs: Memory of String str
    cout << *(ret.back()) << endl; //Outputs: "t"
    return ret;
}
```